# Double JOIN with the same table twice

Tags: mysql

I have a little problem with a query where I would make a double JOIN with the same table twice. I have this 2 tables:

```
list_couples
|id |p_1      |p_2|
|1  |Topolino |Minnie|
|2  |Pippo    |Pluto|
|3  |Paperino |Paperone|

rank
|year |week |player   |points
|2015 |1    |Paperino |200
|2015 |1    |Pippo    |100
|2015 |1    |Paperone |50
|2015 |1    |Topolino |30
|2015 |1    |Minnie   |30
|2015 |2    |Paperino |300
|2015 |2    |Pippo    |150
|2015 |2    |Paperone |50
|2015 |2    |Pluto    |40
```

I would order the couples (p_1 and p_2) in the table list_couples by decreasing sum points of two players for a week in a year.

When players of couple are in the rank table both, my query works, but if one or both not are in rank table, it doesn't as example of week 1 where pluto isn't in the rank table at the week 1.

This my query:

```
SELECT i.*, r.*, r2.*,
             r.points + r2.points AS sum_points
        FROM list_couples AS l
        LEFT JOIN rank AS r  ON l.p_1=r.player
        LEFT JOIN rank AS r2 ON l.p_2=r2.player
        WHERE r.week='$week'  AND r.year='$year' AND
              r2.week='$week' AND r2.year='$year'
        ORDER BY sum_points DESC
```

With this solution I get this results
result

```
|3 |Paperino |Paperone |2015 |1 |300 |2015 |1 |50 |350
|1 |Topolino |Minnie   |2015 |1 |30  |2015 |1 |30 |60
```

instead of this

```
|3 |Paperino |Paperone |2015 |1 |300 |2015 |1 |50   |350
|2 |Pippo    |Pluto    |2015 |1 |100 |2015 |1 |NULL |100
|1 |Topolino |Minnie   |2015 |1 |30  |2015 |1 |30   |60
```

How can I resolve?

Comment: Try Moving the where clause limits that are on t1 and t2 to the JOINs on t1 and t2.   where clause involving `L` can remain in where clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The where clause limits on the left join tables are eliminating the desired results due to null records... So move the limits to the join itself so the limit is applied BEFORE the join, thus keeping the null value records.

```
SELECT i.*,r.*,r2.*, r.points+r2.points AS sum_points
FROM list_couples AS l
LEFT JOIN rank AS r ON l.p_1=r.player
  and r.week='$week' AND r.anno='$anno' 
LEFT JOIN rank AS r2 ON l.p_2=r2.player
  and  r2.week='$week' AND r2.anno='$year'
ORDER BY sum_points DESC
```

Because pluto has no week/year (anno)  then the where clause is eliminating that record.  by moving the limits to the join, the filter is applied before the join occurrs, thus keeping the LEFT outer join.

Put another way, the WHERE Clause is making the left join an inner one!

Comment: Thanks, it works. Just a thing, it's normal that the sum_points is NULL when a player isn't in the rank table? Es. 100+NULL= NULL and not 100?

Comment: @mrball Yes.  anything+ or - null is null.  You can coalesce the value such as coalesce(R.points,0)+ coalesce(r2.points,0) as sum_points to ensure you get desired values however.